# ReOrder Custom ListView in android

Tags: listview, baseadapter

I have a Custom List view made using BaseAdapter in Android. I have completely implemented the ListView Now I want to add the drag and drop functionality in that list view for reordering.
How can i do that? I have got many tutorials but all of them where related to the ListActivity not for base adapter.

Can anybody provide good tutorials for Drag and Drop (Reorder) in Base Adapter Listview.

Thanks